# Finding wrong behaviour from filter resut

Tags: angularjs, angular-filters

I am trying to find the projects by its project ids. For that, I am using this filter method:

```
$scope.filteredPro = $filter('filter')( project.ProjectSummaryFilter, {"ProjectId" : "1" } );
```

But when I am getting the result, the project which has the id as `1` and `10` appears as well.. in this case if I make my filter using only by `10` like this:

```
$scope.filteredPro = $filter('filter')( project.ProjectSummaryFilter, {"ProjectId" : "10" } );
```

I am exactly getting the result from the id of `10`. How can fix this?

Why am I getting a result including the project which has the id of `10` as well when I filter by `1`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

for an exact match, you should try:

```
$scope.filteredPro = $filter('filter')( project.ProjectSummaryFilter, {"ProjectId" : "1" },true );
```

> $filter('filter')(array, expression, comparator)

where expression:

> Object: A pattern object can be used to filter specific properties on objects contained by array. For example {name:"M", phone:"1"} predicate will return an array of items which have property name containing "M" and property phone containing "1"

where comparator value:

> true: A shorthand for function(actual, expected) { return angular.equals(actual, expected)}. This is essentially strict comparison of expected and actual.

Comment: As a suggession, I would like to filter by `{name:"M", phone:"1"}  | {name:"S", phone:"1"} ` - so testing both name `M` or name `S`

Comment: I guess you would need to write a custom filter function for that

Answer (score 0):

When you do `"ProjectId": "1"` in your filter, you are filtering all project ids which have 1 as part of the string, thus fullfilling cases for '1' and '10'.

So, replace

```
"ProjectId" : "1"
```

by

```
"ProjectId" : 1 //integer
```

Comment: In case of hard-code it could be work, what about the dynamic declarations like instead of `1` `var st = "10"`